# Can JSP not access inherited methods?

Tags: java, jsp, inheritance, polymorphism, portlet

I'm getting a method not found exception in a piece of code, simplified here.

```
public class myOverriddenPortlet {
//usual doView, etc.
protected void myPrintMethod (
    javax.portlet.PortletRequest req, 
    javax.portlet.PortletResponse res, 
    javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter out
) {
    //dostuff
   }
}

public class myPortlet extends myOverriddenPortlet {
    //usual portlet stuff
}
```

And in the jsp

```
<%myPrintMethod(request, response, out); %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can JSP not access inherited methods?

If you are talking about JSP inherting from other classes then , no JSP cannot inherit other classes  . Your *JSP* will be compiled to a *Servlet* which in turn will extend some implementation class of `JspBase` , hence it cannot extend other class.

Answer (score 1):

protected methods can only be called from within the class, classes in the same package, or subclasses. Your compiled JSP is none of these.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Comment: Thanks, I had assumed that the final compiled class included the extends and implements from the portlets it was rendering

Answer (score 0):

Your method require this :

```
protected void myPrintMethod (
    javax.portlet.PortletRequest req, 
    javax.portlet.PortletResponse res, 
    javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter out
)
```

But you are providing

```
request - I guess its an object of HttpRequest
response- I guess its an object of HttpResponse
```

So try making your method accept these types or generic types

Comment: Thanks but this is not the issue, PortletRequest is a supertype of the portlet render and action request objects and the same for response